# SecurityContext.getAuthentication() returns null after Vaadin navigation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, vaadin

I'm doing an order managing web applicaton in Vaadin and Spring Boot in my thesis.

```java
@Slf4j
@Route("app/end-user/sent")
public class SentToRestaurantView extends EndUserViewBase {
    Registration broadcasterRegistration;

    public SentToRestaurantView() {
        super("Sent to restaurant");

        add(
                new H1("Your order has been sent"),
                new H2("The restaurant has received your order. They will respond with a time estimate in a few minutes.")
        );
    }


    private void onUpdate(String message) {
        // here is the redirect
        UI.getCurrent().navigate(InTheMakingView.class);
        log.info(message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {
        UI ui = attachEvent.getUI();
        broadcasterRegistration = Broadcaster.register(newMessage -> ui.access(() -> onUpdate(newMessage)));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetach(DetachEvent detachEvent) {
        broadcasterRegistration.remove();
        broadcasterRegistration = null;
    }
}
```

The user gets this view after sending their order to the restaurant. If the restaurant accepts it (and broadcasts a message), I want to redirect the user to an other view; you can see that in SentToRestaurantView::onUpdate. Problem is, during that redirection, an error occurs.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.demo.ui.enduser.view.InTheMakingView': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.demo.ui.enduser.view.InTheMakingView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.core.Authentication.getPrincipal()" because the return value of "org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext.getAuthentication()" is null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:296) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:332) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator.getOrCreate(SpringInstantiator.java:117) ~[vaadin-spring-18.0.0.jar:na]
        at com.vaadin.flow.di.Instantiator.createRouteTarget(Instantiator.java:193) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.lambda$getRouteTarget$1(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:135) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
        at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.getRouteTarget(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:134) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.sendBeforeEnterEventAndPopulateChain(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:488) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.createChainIfEmptyAndExecuteBeforeEnterNavigation(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:469) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.handle(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:207) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptNavigationStateRenderer.handle(JavaScriptNavigationStateRenderer.java:79) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI.handleNavigation(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:315) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI.navigate(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:223) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.UI.navigate(UI.java:917) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.UI.navigate(UI.java:898) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.UI.navigate(UI.java:834) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.example.demo.ui.enduser.view.SentToRestaurantView.onUpdate(SentToRestaurantView.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.example.demo.ui.enduser.view.SentToRestaurantView.lambda$onAttach$b3eb7f9f$1(SentToRestaurantView.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.UI.accessSynchronously(UI.java:446) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.UI.access$000(UI.java:97) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.UI$2.execute(UI.java:521) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.runPendingAccessTasks(VaadinService.java:2039) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession.unlock(VaadinSession.java:720) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.ensureAccessQueuePurged(VaadinService.java:2005) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.accessSession(VaadinService.java:1972) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession.access(VaadinSession.java:1023) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.UI.access(UI.java:518) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.vaadin.flow.component.UI.access(UI.java:501) ~[flow-server-8.0.4.jar:8.0.4]
        at com.example.demo.ui.enduser.view.SentToRestaurantView.lambda$onAttach$0(SentToRestaurantView.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.example.demo.backend.broadcast.Broadcaster.lambda$broadcast$0(Broadcaster.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.demo.ui.enduser.view.InTheMakingView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.core.Authentication.getPrincipal()" because the return value of "org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext.getAuthentication()" is null
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.core.Authentication.getPrincipal()" because the return value of "org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext.getAuthentication()" is null
        at com.example.demo.security.user.enduser.service.details.EndUserDetailsServiceImpl.getUser(EndUserDetailsServiceImpl.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.example.demo.ui.enduser.view.EndUserViewBase.<init>(EndUserViewBase.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.example.demo.ui.enduser.view.InTheMakingView.<init>(InTheMakingView.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        ... 41 common frames omitted
```

```java
@Route("app/end-user/waiting")
@Slf4j
public class InTheMakingView extends EndUserViewBase {
    @Autowired
    public InTheMakingView(EndUserDetailsService endUserDetailsService) {
        super("In the making");

        var order = endUserDetailsService.getUser().getTable().getOrderSession().getLastOrder();

        add(
                new H1("Your order is in the making"),
                new H2(String.format("In about %d minutes our college, %s, will serve you your meal", order.getEstimatedTimeOfDoingInMinutes(), order.getServer().getName()))
        );
    }
}
```

```java
@Slf4j
public abstract class EndUserViewBase extends ViewBase {
    protected EndUserViewBase(String title) {
        super(title);

        var detailsService = BeanUtil.getBean(EndUserDetailsService.class);

        add(
                new Header(String.format(
                        "%s | %s",
                        detailsService.getUser().getTable().getRestaurant().getName(),
                        title))
        );
    }
}
```

Apparently, a call to `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` in a method of EndUserDetaulsService returns null in the constructor of EndUserViewBase. After I refresh the page, it works as intended.

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
public class EndUserDetailsServiceImpl implements EndUserDetailsService{
    @Autowired
    EndUserService endUserService;

    @Override
    public EndUser getUser() {
        var principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        String userId = "";

        // TOPIC pattern matching
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails userDetails) {
            userId = userDetails.getUsername();
        }

        var user =
                endUserService.getUser(userId);

        if (user.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("User with email %s was not found", userId));
        } else {
            return user.get();
        }

    }
}
```

I can't work out the source of this error, and how is it related to the navigation, or why not manifest if I reload the page, that crashed before.

Answer (score 1):

Your `EndUserDetailsServiceImpl` is a singleton Service, thus `SecurityContextHolder` is not available there. You need to refactor your code so that `SecurityContextHolder` is not used in the service. You need to pass the `userId` as a parameter.

```
public EndUser getUser(String userId) {
    // TOPIC pattern matching
    if (principal instanceof UserDetails userDetails) {
        userId = userDetails.getUsername();
    }

    var user =
            endUserService.getUser(userId);

    if (user.isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("User with email %s was not found", userId));
    } else {
        return user.get();
    }

}
```

I.e. get the `userId` from the principal and then call the method.

```
public InTheMakingView(EndUserDetailsService endUserDetailsService) {
    super("In the making");

    var principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    String userId = "";

    // TOPIC pattern matching
    if (principal instanceof UserDetails userDetails) {
        userId = userDetails.getUsername();
    }

    var order = endUserDetailsService.getUser(userId).getTable().getOrderSession().getLastOrder();

    add(
            new H1("Your order is in the making"),
            new H2(String.format("In about %d minutes our college, %s, will serve you your meal", order.getEstimatedTimeOfDoingInMinutes(), order.getServer().getName()))
    );
}
```